When querying a simple table in MySql, the row values appear as NULL. How do I get my query to show the row values?
I created a table called "Author" and inserted row values into it in MySql. When I query the table with SELECT * FROM Author; the result will show the columns but not row values.


I assume I have some kind of white space or syntax problem, but I cant seem to figure it out.

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Can't reproduce: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vS69RjwCbxRzpBJVKsVoYx/0

It looks like you just didn't run the 2nd query (insert). My IDE for MySQL (dbeaver) doesn't automatically run all the queries on the screen, just the one where the cursor is. Or there's a button that says "execute sql script" which will run all of the queries in turn.
